# C++ serial port library, with modern C++ style, compact and not overly abstract API

Tags: library, c++, communication

I'm looking for a C++ serial port library to communicate between a PC running Windows and microcontroller board or (virtual) serial peripheral. I need just the basic functionality. I prefer a modern C++ style, compact and not overly abstract API.

I looked at [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), but I found it too complex with steep learning curve. I prefer something similar to [Serial Communication Library](https://github.com/wjwwood/serial). Any suggestions?

**Edit**

It doesn't have to be open source. Preferably free or below $100. There is nothing wrong with Serial Communication Library I know of, but I would like to see more options before I commit to one or the other.

Comment: Open source? Free? Or what budget?

Comment: I'm still bot 100% sure what you are looking for. Since you say that you prefer something similar to Serial Communication Library, but don't want to use it, can you tell us what is wrong with it? Maybe that will help us to recommend something

Comment: Or can you tell us why you don't just use the standard .NET stuff? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: @Mawg `why you don't just use the standard .NET stuff` The main reason is that I'm working with C++ not C#. I also heard about many issues with System.IO.Ports::SerialPort.

Comment: @Mawg`what is wrong with it` There is nothing wrong with it - just looking for more options.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I just edited my question with these details.